# link over the image when user hover the image in css3

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is a link itself. I want to show another link(name of the link) over this image when the user hover it and that will be the link to other page

---

.
I need to know how this link will be visible over the image with some styling like link border property,opacity,background-color,middle-align..

---

I am having Load's of problems. so kindly help! how can i make it??

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div and put both anchors inside; one of them with `display: none`. Then we show that anchor when the user hover on the main div.

```css
.image {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}

.image a { display: block; }

 .image a.hidden-url {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;

  background: black;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .image:hover a.hidden-url { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="hidden-url">Go to Google instead</a>
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/?text=StackOverflow" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have fun.

```js
$('.container').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.link').fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
  });
  $('.link').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.link').fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url(https://s3.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/stories/t2/Golden_Retriever_4677_5288.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
.link {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.link a {
  width: 50x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
<div class='link'>
  <a href='www.google.com'>LINK</a>
</div>
```